# WPF DataGrid: Efficient method to obtain Row Index of a Cell

Tags: wpf, datagrid

There are zillions of questions all over the web, including `StackOverflow` ([WPF DataGrid: How to Determine the Current Row Index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20169765/) and [WPF Datagrid cell, cellinfo and selectedcells + custom selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066320/) for example) on this topic. My problem with answers to those questions is that they need a linear search in items which is not efficient.

I noticed that `DataGridCellInfo` has an `internal` property named `ItemInfo` which in turn has a property named `Index`. This `Index` is exactly what I am looking for. Why is this property designed to be not `public`? How is the correct way of accessing it?

Please note that I want to work with `SelectionUnit="Cell"` and thus `SelectedIndex` always is equal to `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something here.
If you have datagridcellinfo for a cell.

```
myDataGrid.Items.IndexOf(datagridcellinfo.Item)
```

Comment: Using `IndexOf` is actually a linear search among all `Items` and is not efficient.